# Strange characters at beginning of line in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn Spring Boot and I'm using VSCode. I've written some code and changed a file and suddenly these "s: s:" appear at the beginning of some lines. They are not in the file, my code works as expected but I can't remove them in VSCode.

Where are these characters coming from and what do they mean?

I don't even have an idea how to call them and thus I wasn't able to google about them, so I add a screenshot here.

Can anyone tell me something about these "hints" (?)? What do they mean? Can I disable them? Or shouldn't I disable them since they want to tell me something?

[image]

Thanks!
Wolfgang

Comment: Does VS Code do anything if you hover over them?

Comment: No, nothing. Maybe that would have given me an idea about the meaning or the “responsible” extension. But: nothing.

Comment: VS Code has a mechanism for debugging extensions, which you could use if you have no idea which it could be. It does a binary search through them, on each step disabling the problematic half and asking you if the problem is still there.